# Google Map tiles not loading in Bootstrap-Modal

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

Im trying to open a map in a Bootstrap-Modal.
When I open the Modal tiles of the basemap are not loading, but if I open/close the Google Chrome Developers console the tiles suddenly load like a charm. I also wanna mention that another map on the website (not in a modal) works like it should.

I've been searching on the Internet for hours but I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

I tried `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` but it didn't fix my problem.

How can I get the tiles to load automatically when the modal is shown?

EDIT:
"Mr. Engineers" comment did the job, thank you!

> Refer this : bootply.com/106707 – Mr. Engineer

Comment: Refer this : http://www.bootply.com/106707

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

P.S. Can you make an example?